# Is there a way to auto-size a UIImageView in Interface Builder/storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

When you set a image for a uiimageview in storyboard or interface builder, it retains the shape of the original `UIImageView`, which means that the image itself is completely distorted.

To match the size of the `UIImageView` to its image, I have to manually enter in the size from the file inspector.

Is there a way that `UIImageView` can automatically detect the native size of its image and size its self accordingly?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to layout in storyboard/IB.  To get the native size of the image just select the image and press **Command** + **=** on the keyboard.  the to re-size it proportionally select the corner and hold down the shift key when you re-size it.

Comment: Great shortcut! Is there a way to set the image at half its size native size (for @2x retina images)?

Comment: You don't need to account for retina resolution unless you're doing something unusual. iOS will automatically substitute the @2x image at the correct size. Just use the non-retina image in IB.

Comment: ```Command``` + ```=``` does the trick. Menu command is ```Editor -> Size to Fit Content```

Comment: You might need to click the UIImageView a second time (so that it highlights) before the menu option becomes available.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you set the size of your uiimageview in code?
Here's what you need to do...

```
//get the Image
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];

CGFloat x = img.origin.x;
CGFloat y = img.origin.y;
CGFloat width = img.size.width;
CGFloat height = img.size.height;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);  //imageView is your uiimageview's reference
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this through the Storyboard/IB interface?

Comment: Not sure as I don't have my mac right now with me. I don't think so you can change size in IB/Storyboard. Because connections with the outlets aren't actually done until viewDidLoad method is called, so you would still see nil if you try to access the imageview before this method is called.

Answer (score 1):

Use the contentMode

```
 imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

**Edit** :
I just saw you seem to want to adjust imageViews size to the image.... Different then

Answer (score -4):

This is what I did:

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[imageView setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

That is working for me.